# Check if IP Address and Port are responding

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I'm currently developing a autodiscover feature for SNMP printer monitor software. I need a helper method, which is executed from several threads each checking an ip in a range, to determine if a device at a certain ip address, is responding to port 9100, to establish that it in fact is a printer, before sending an SNMP request to it.

I've ended up with the following method, however im unaware if this is the correct approach, and if it by convention is correct use of the Close() method in this context (I can see that Dispose(), Disconnect() and Shutdown() methods are also available, so which to use?). Furthermore i need to set a timeout value of max. 5 seconds, so the threads won't linger for too long, before presenting a result. My code so far:

```
private bool GetTCPPrinterResponse(IPAddress _ip)
{
        int port = 9100;

        bool isResponsive = false;

        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            s.Connect(_ip, port);

            isResponsive = true;
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            isResponsive = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            s.Close();
        }

        return isResponsive;
    }
```

After method edit:

```
private bool GetTCPPrinterResponse(IPAddress _ip)
        {
            int port = 9100;

            bool isResponsive = false;

            using (Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
            {
                s.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;
                s.SendTimeout = 3000;

                try
                {
                    s.Connect(_ip, port);

                    isResponsive = true;
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    isResponsive = false;
                }
            }

            return isResponsive;
        }
```

Setting of Timeout properties, has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct way to check if a computer/printer is online at a certain IP on a certain Port.
You should call the dispose method to release the memory being used by the object.
Socket class implements IDisposable, so it would be best if you use `using` and not worry about calling dispose because `using` does it for you.

```
using(Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
//...
}
```

Socket class has properties ReceiveTimeout and SendTimeout.

Comment: `Dispose` doesn't "release the memory being used by the object". Dispose is for releasing *unmanaged* resources. Okay, that may include some unmanaged memory buffers in this case, but it certainly doesn't include the memory used by the object. That memory is released by the GC at some future point in time, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, for your contribution. I've rewritten the method, to utilize the Socket class implementation of IDisposable, and added timeout values. However, the latter seems to have no effect. The method, returns a result after what seems to be 15 seconds (I suspect this to be the default timeout value).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use multi-threading for this. You're tying up threads that will end up waiting for the I/O operation to complete anyway. Instead, why not use asynchronous I/O?

```
public async Task<Tuple<IPAddress, bool>> GetResponse(IPAddress address)
{
  using (var client = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
  {
    var connectTask = client.ConnectAsync(address, 80);

    await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, Task.Delay(5000));

    if (connectTask.IsCompleted)
        return Tuple.Create(address, true);
    else
        return Tuple.Create(address, false);
  }
}
```

This can further be improved - the timeout mechanism is somewhat wasteful (`Task.Delay` uses a timer, not really necessary), but it's easy to write, understand and use, and it doesn't unnecessarily waste threads.

The call would then be something like this:

```
Task<Tuple<IPAddress, bool>>[] tasks = 
    new []
    {
      GetResponse(Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.google.com").First()),
      GetResponse(Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.microsoft.com").First()),
      GetResponse(Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.yahoo.com").First()),
      GetResponse(Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.altavista.com").First()),
    };

Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();

foreach (var t in tasks)
    t.Result.Dump(); // t.Result has the IP address and status
```

This will wait for all of the devices to respond (or timeout). Of course, there's nothing preventing you from doing this in a more interactive fashion - you could just as easily update the UI with the data as it comes back.